# Currency conversion using available rates

Tags: arithmetic, finance

I have the following rates available:

```
USD -> USD = 1
USD -> EUR = 0.887662
USD -> GBP = 0.654514
```

I want to calculate the following rates

```
GBP -> EUR
EUR -> GBP
```

Using only the first 3 rates.

My process so far has been:

```
1 USD / 0.654514 GBP = 1.527851
So
1 GBP = 1.53 USD

1 USD / 0.887662 = 1.126554
So
1 EUR = 1.13 USD
```

I assume I have all the data needed now to calculate the following conversions

```
GBP -> EUR
EUR -> GBP
```

From this point however, I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: $1$ USD $= 0.887662$ EUR; 

$1$ USD $= 0.654514$ GBP; 

$\therefore 0.887662$ EUR $= 0.654514$ GBP; 

$\therefore 1 $ EUR $= \frac{0.654514}{0.887662}=0.73734$ GBP; 

and $1$ GBP $= \frac{0.887662}{0.654514}= 1.356$ EUR.

Answer (score 1):

We know the exchange rates $\frac{$}{€}=0.887662$ and $\frac{$}{£}=0.654514$. So we have

$$
\frac{€}{£}=\frac{$}{£}\times\frac{€}{$}=\frac{$}{£}\times \frac{1}{$/€}=0.654514\times \frac{1}{0.887662}=\frac{0.654514}{0.887662}=0.737346
$$
and
$$
\frac{£}{€}= \frac{1}{€/£}=\frac{1}{0.737346}=1.356215
$$